# Why does gnu-sed with -i require everything to be escaped?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm working with `gnu-sed` and I've found the following:

```
sed -r 's|((https?://)?(www\.)?)example\.com\.au|\1|gi' test.txt
```

Without `-i`, this will work just fine and match the following line in `test.txt`:

```
https://www.example.com.au
```

However if I add `-i`, I need to escape pretty much everything (**even the question marks**) to achieve the same result. It ends up looking like:

```
     sed -ir 's|\(\(https\?://\)\?\(www\.\)\?\)example\.com\.au|\1|gi' test.txt
#COMP:sed -r 's|((https?://)?(www\.)?)example\.com\.au|\1|gi' test.txt
```

This is much uglier... I don't like it :(

I couldn't find anything in `man sed` to explain this.

**Why is this happening and is there any way around it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A short excerpt from the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

> `-i[SUFFIX]`
>   `--in-place[=SUFFIX]`
>       This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.

When you write:

```
sed -ir '...'
```

`sed` interprets the command line as `-i` followed by the suffix to use for the backup files (the short form presented in the above excerpt).

Accordingly, it doesn't see the `-r` option any more and interprets the last argument as a basic `regex` and not as an extended `regex`. As the same documentation page says, *"Extended regexps [...] can be clearer because they usually have less backslashes"*.

The solutions is very simple: add your `-i` command line option separate, **do not** combine it with `-r`:

```
sed -i -r 's|((https?://)?(www\.)?)example\.com\.au|\1|gi'
```

*(Command line options that have arguments cannot be combined.)*

Comment: “Command line options that have arguments cannot be combined.” This is not quite true; an option with an argument can follow a non-argument option, so `sed -ri ...` would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `-i` option expects a file argument. If you switch the arguments to `-ri`, you'll see the error. Having it as `-ir` tells sed to read from file `r` and thus it does not use the extended regex options that are enabled with the `-r` option.

Comment: Oh sorry @mart1n, in practice I am supplying a file to it, but it won't match and make edits to that file unless I add all of those slashes. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Ohhhh I understand now! Sorry, this is correct, it just took me a while to see that the `-i` itself expected a file, not the whole script.

Comment: @mart1n, you said "Having it as `-ir` tells sed to read from file `r` ...", and it does no such thing!  It treats `r` in `-ir` as the suffix, as in "-i[SUFFIX]" from the man page as shown in axiac's correct answer.

Comment: `sed -ir PATTERN file.txt` backs up `file.txt` to `file.txtr` before editing in-place, so is effectively `cp file.txt file.txtr && sed PATTERN file.txtr > file.txt`.